# How to use CABasicAnimation and CALayer to animate a bezier path

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, caanimation

I'm trying to animate color change of a bezier path in a UIView but I think I'm missing something very basic as the layer is not being rendered in my UI View.  Just adding the layer to self.layer doesn't seem to trigger the draw in context method.  I don't really understand the basics of which draw is being triggered when and into which layers.

```
public class ProgressIndicatorView: UIView {


    var bubble = BubbleLayer()

    public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public class var sharedInstance: ProgressIndicatorView {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = ProgressIndicatorView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.updateFrame(frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.3)
        self.layer.addSublayer(bubble)

    }


    func updateFrame(frame:CGRect)
    {
        self.frame = frame
        bubble.frame = CGRect(x:self.center.x, y:self.center.y, width: 126, height: 126)
    }

    func animate(){

        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"percentage")
        anim.fromValue = 0.000
        anim.toValue = 1.000
        anim.repeatCount = 1000
        bubble.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "percentage")

    }


    public class func show() {

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first as UIWindow
        let indicator = ProgressIndicatorView.sharedInstance
        indicator.updateFrame(window.frame)

        if indicator.superview == nil {

            window.addSubview(indicator)
            indicator.animate()
        }
    }

    public class func hide(){

        let indicator = ProgressIndicatorView.sharedInstance

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            indicator.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: {_ in
                indicator.alpha = 1.0
                indicator.removeFromSuperview()

        })

    }
}

public class BubbleLayer : CALayer {

    public var percentage:CGFloat = 0

    public override func animationForKey(key: String!) -> CAAnimation! {
        var anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
        anim.fromValue = self.presentationLayer().key
        anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        anim.duration = CATransaction.animationDuration()

        return anim
    }

    public override func actionForKey(event: String!) -> CAAction! {
        if (event == "percentage"){
            return self.animationForKey(event)
        }
        else {
            return super.actionForKey(event)
        }
    }

    public override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {
        super.drawInContext(ctx)
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let frame = self.bounds


        let white = UIColor(red: self.percentage, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 1.000)
        let white_20 = UIColor(red: self.percentage, green: 1.000, blue: 1.000, alpha: 0.200)

        //// Oval 10 Drawing
        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 1.3, 0.8)

        var oval10Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(5, 5, 113.6, 113.6))
        white_20.setStroke()
        oval10Path.lineWidth = 10
        oval10Path.stroke()

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

        //// Bezier 122 Drawing
        var bezier122Path = UIBezierPath()
        bezier122Path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(63, 5.9))
        bezier122Path.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(119.8, 62.7), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(94.4, 5.9), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(119.8, 31.3))
        bezier122Path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

        bezier122Path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

        white.setStroke()
        bezier122Path.lineWidth = 10
        bezier122Path.stroke()


    }

}
```

Comment: You are not providing `anim.toValue` in your `animationForKey` function. Could be due to this

Comment: `animationForKey:` does not do what either of you think. It returns an animation that has already been added to a layer, for a given key. The key is simply an identifier.